# How to draw a box around a set of nodes in pydot or networkx

Tags: python

I have used pydot and networkx to build and show my graph. I have two questions:

1. How can I differentiate between the nodes with similar names?
   For instance, there are two nodes with different values, but I want to show both of them with 'node_x' in my graph.
2. How can I draw a rectangle around a set of nodes in my graph?